# Define integer ranges in C

Tags: c, typedef

I want to define a type named `Int_1_100_Type` which is an `integer` variable in the range from 1 to 100.
How should I define this one?
for example:
I am passing this variable to a function which accepts variable of type `Int_1_100_Type`,
`funca(Int_1_100_Type Var1)`

Comment: Why the downvote? Just because what the OP wants to do can't be done in C, doesn't mean the question isn't clear enough and reasonable.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If your function needs input in a particular range, you can just do bounds-checking on a regular `int` variable.

Comment: @tzaman If the language supports it (and some do) it's a nice feature and avoids writing range checks all over the place.

Answer (score 7):

You can't, C has no such functionality. You can of course typedef an int:

```
typedef int int_1_100_Type;
```

but there is no way of restricting its range. In C++, you could create a new type with this functionality, but I think very few people would bother - you just need to put range checks in the function(s) that use the type.

Comment: Perhaps one could fake it with an `enum`, if one was clinically insane? Of course, even that wouldn't prevent anyone from passing in any old integer.

Comment: Not really. An enum always has a range that includes 0, and the number of possible values is always a power of 2. Classical example: the range of `enum rights {Read = 1, Write = 2};` includes 0 (no rights) and 3 (both).

Comment: You could even `typedef` a `char` in this case.

Comment: @MSalters: not true.  That is a common use case of an enumeration, yes, but the bitwise combinations of enumerations are not technically a part of the enumeration. The whole thing is rather worthless, though, since you can store any value into an `enum` typed variable.

Comment: @Matt B: that's why I said they were part of **the range**. And you're wrong wrt to "any value". The standard certainly doesn't guarantee that you can cast INT_MAX to `enum rights` from my previous example, e.g. when `sizeof(rights) < sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can. All you need is a little object-based C.

create a file with a struct and some members

```
typedef struct s_foo {
  int member;
} Foo;

Foo* newFoo(int input);   // ctor
void get(Foo *f);         // accessor
```

Enforce your condition in the mutator/ctor

If you do this in its own file, you can hide the impl of the class as well, you can do oo-like C

Comment: (Grr... no formating in comments) 

In the recent months I've learnt an even better way of doing this. It's a little elaborate, but here's the short version. add "newFoo" and "get" as a members of the struct Foo (members that hold function pointers), and you can implement "newFoo" and "get" as static functions in a separate C file, as long as you have a builder for Foo (that would provide encapsulation, implementation- hiding (some level), and a nice abstract interface to create objects of type Foo)

Answer (score 2):

You can't put that kind of limit on the range of an integer.

You can of course `typedef` it anyway:

```
typedef int int_1_100;
```

or even better:

```
typedef unsigned int int_1_100;
```

But nothing in C will prevent you from writing:

```
int_1_100 x = 1000;
```

To implement something like that, you need to hide the implementation, but that will make it harder to initialize the value (and impossible to allocate values of the type on the stack, with the hiding intact).

Comment: From an over 5 years distance since you wrote this answer wanna ask you something. How is 2nd `typedef` **even better** than 1st one? Only difference is that you have to type more in 2nd case. Both have required range covered (1-100), both consume same space, both have same amount of values out of range, right? Atop of all, as you know `int` is multibyte type (# of bytes used by `int` depend on CPU/OS), why not using only `char` as type which is basically `int` that always requires 1 single byte and covers range 1-100 (works also for `unsigned char`, but again - longer to type). Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, there would be a way to do this by writing a class that would act like an integer, but it would be way too much effort and way too heavyweight a solution to be practical.

Thanks Naveen for pointing out the question was C only.

Comment: question is tagged as c not c++.

Comment: Uh, yes my bad... This would indeed only be possible in C++

Answer (score 1):

There's no way in c to define a type that must be in a specific range. You could however check each value in your functions, e.g.

```
int funca(int Var1)
{
    assert(Var1 >= 1);
    assert(Var1 < 101);
    ...
}
```